# have to I add on every query a release?

Tags: node.js, pg

I have this query:

```
const data = async () => {
  try {
   await client.query('SELECT * FROM data');
 } catch(e) {
   return e;
 }
};
```

but I see that people use it like this:

```
const data = async () => {
  try {
   await client.query('SELECT * FROM data');
 } catch(e) {
   return e;
 } finally {
  client.release();
}
};
```

so whats the difference and should I use method 2 ?

Comment: Unrelated: is this the actual code? It doesn't return data, and returns an exception **instead** of data, which seems counter-intuitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using `node-postgres`.

You should not call `client.release()` for every query you run with `client.query()`. You have to call `client.release()` once (and only once) when you are done with the the database connection `client`.

Where and when you should call `client.release()` depends on the structure of your application.

If you just need to run one query, it is better to just use `pool.query()` instead of checkout a client.